# List only max date using two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Items and calibrations tables. One item can have many calibrations. I need list the items with their date_expired calibrations, but only show the item with the "MAX" date_expired (witch is the date that has to be calibrated). Means that if one item has 2 calibrations only list the item with the MAX date. Using postgress and ruby.
I have something like this, don't know if it's exist a better way using where..

```
SELECT *, date_expired  
FROM   Items  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calibrations    
ON   Calibrations.item_id = Items.id   
GROUP BY Items.id, calibrations.date_expired  
HAVING calibrations.date_expired ...
```

If you can help me, don't know where introduced MAX(date_expired). Tks

UPDATE
Items
id          name
1           AAA
2           BBB
3           CCC

Calibrations
id         item_id       date_expired
1          1             2014/12/12
2          1             2015/12/12

Result
id         name          date_exired
1          AAA           2015/12/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.id) 
    i.id, i.name, c.date_expired
FROM Items i
JOIN Calibrations c ON c.item_id = i.id
ORDER BY i.id, c.date_expired desc
```

With `JOIN` and not `LEFT JOIN` you get only the items with calibrations. Then DISTINCT ON filters the results giving you a single calibration per item. Since its choice is based on the order, ordering by `date_expired desc` give us always the most recent calibration.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.Id, MAX(c.date_expired )
FROM Items i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calibrations c ON I.id = C.item_id
GROUP BY Items.id
```

Comment: Tks but that show me all the items, I need list only the items who has been calibrated and select the MAX date_expired, so if one item has 3 calibrations, i have to list only the max. See the update

Comment: How do you know if they have been calibrated?

Comment: Because if the item have a date_expired, means that has a date_calibrated. So.. you will see a date-calibrated and date_expired, a item is calibrated one for year..normally